# Arduino combine several arrays (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

I want to know how can I combine several byte arrays into 1?

I have this:

```
 byte MessageStart [] = {0x02};
 byte Next [] = {0x5C , 0x73}; 
 byte messgae[] = {0x30 , 0x35};
 byte BeforeEnd [] = {0x5C , 0x3B};
 byte MessageEnd [] = {0x03};
```

I want to have one byte array with all of them, the final result needs to be:

```
byte Final [] = {0x02, 0x5C, 0x73, 0x30, 0x35, 0x5C, 0x3B, 0x03}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"? What should the end-result be?

Comment: You know the size of the resulting array (since you know the sizes of all source arrays). That means you can allocate the memory needed for `Final` easily. Then it's just a matter of copying the elements from each source array to the correct place in the `FInal` array, and this can easily be accomplished by a few loops and using a common index for `Final`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
  byte *concatbytes(const byte *source, byte *destination, int length)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
      *destination++ = *source++;
    }

    return destination;
  }

  ...

  byte MessageStart[] = { 0x02 };
  byte Next[] = { 0x5C , 0x73 };
  byte messgae[] = { 0x30 , 0x35 };
  byte BeforeEnd[] = { 0x5C , 0x3B };
  byte MessageEnd[] = { 0x03 };

  byte Final[8];       // 8 is the hardcoded length of sum of all 5 arrays

  byte *dest = Final;    
  dest = concatbytes(dest, MessageStart, sizeof(MessageStart));
  dest = concatbytes(dest, Next, sizeof(Next));
  dest = concatbytes(dest, messgae, sizeof(messgae));
  dest = concatbytes(dest, BeforeEnd, sizeof(BeforeEnd));
  dest = concatbytes(dest, MessageEnd, sizeof(Next));
```

The `Final` array may be obtained differently, for example by dynamic memory allocation. This is left as an exercise for the reader.